# How to download all images from a site on the C# + HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I use programs such as: Teleport, HTTrack, Offline Explorer, DownThemAll and others. All pictures are found only - DownThemAll. But I have a lot of pages, with which you want to download pictures of the goods. DownThemAll is not suitable.

I wrote the program on C# + HtmlAgilityPack, but she didn't find all the pictures of the goods.

Ideally, I'd like the following:

1. The program loads the file URLS.txt. In which such references are:

> http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/televizori-c181/
>
> http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/3d_ochki-c130/
>
> etc

2. The program loads on these pages all the pictures of the goods.

What do you advise? Maybe I'm wrong to write the code on C#?

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string url = wc.DownloadString("http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/televizori-c181/");
doc.LoadHtml(url);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='catalog__displayedItem__columnFotomainLnk']/img");

if (nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
                {                    
                    listBox1.Items.Add(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going well. In this solution I am using LINQ and TPL.

This site use pagination, so you must load all pages to be able to download all product's images.

1. Load first page (HtmlNode)
2. Discover how many pages this product catalogue have
3. Load other pages (HtmlNode)

Then you have a collection of pages

1. Load img nodes that you want to download
2. Create a tuple with de Image url and new WebClient instance¹
3. Download image

```
public class ImageDownloader
{
    public void DownloadImagesFromUrl(string url, string folderImagesPath)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url + "/?per_page=50");
        var pages = new List<HtmlNode> { LoadHtmlDocument(uri) };

        pages.AddRange(LoadOtherPages(pages[0], url));

        pages.SelectMany(p => p.SelectNodes("//a[@class='catalog__displayedItem__columnFotomainLnk']/img"))
             .Select(node => Tuple.Create(new UriBuilder(uri.Scheme, uri.Host, uri.Port, node.Attributes["src"].Value).Uri, new WebClient()))
             .AsParallel()
             .ForAll(t => DownloadImage(folderImagesPath, t.Item1, t.Item2));
    }

    private static void DownloadImage(string folderImagesPath, Uri url, WebClient webClient)
    {
        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadFile(url, Path.Combine(folderImagesPath, Path.GetFileName(url.ToString())));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> LoadOtherPages(HtmlNode firstPage, string url)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, DiscoverTotalPages(firstPage))
                         .AsParallel()
                         .Select(i => LoadHtmlDocument(new Uri(url + "/?per_page=50&page=" + i)));
    }

    private static int DiscoverTotalPages(HtmlNode documentNode)
    {
        var totalItemsDescription = documentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='catalogItemList__numsInWiev']").First().InnerText.Trim();
        var totalItems = int.Parse(Regex.Match(totalItemsDescription, @"\d+$").ToString());
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalItems / 50d);
        return totalPages;
    }

    private static HtmlNode LoadHtmlDocument(Uri uri)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        var wc = new WebClient();
        doc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString(uri));

        var documentNode = doc.DocumentNode;
        return documentNode;
    }
}
```

And you can use like that:

```
DownloadImagesFromUrl("http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/televizori-c181/", @"C:\temp\televizori-c181\images");
```

And then 178 images were downloaded.

When images are downloading, sometimes it can fail, so I suggest you to implement [Retry pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589788.aspx) using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

**Obs¹**: WebClient dont support parallel operation, so I create one for each image url.

Comment: Thank you.
But again the same problem: not all pictures were loaded. On this page, 50 images, and download only the 10.

Comment: @program23 Changed code, now will download all images

Comment: I need to upload images is a "class = catalog __displayedItem__column FotomainLnk".
Why does not find all links to the image?

Comment: @program23 you need to download only the product's images?

Comment: @program23 So my previous version was right, downloading 10 images.

Comment: @program23 lets talk in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99016/question-34463581

Comment: @program23 the first link of TVs, show 10 products, but there is 178 , you want to download all 178 images?

Comment: @program23 And the second link just contains 6 3d glasses

Comment: @program23 In this site it allows you to show a maximum of 50 items

Comment: I have little reputation to enter the chat.
I want to download 50 items. Or 178, if possible.)

Comment: @program23 Ok, now I can do that :D

Comment: @program23 Are you using C# 6?

Comment: @program23 I changed the answer, now it will download all images

Comment: Thank you so much!
You helped me a lot.

Comment: @program23 You are welcome!!